# fix rotate 3D object Perl code

Tags: perl, 3d

I wrote this code using C++ example from net to rotate my set of points in 3D.

```
#@matrix is points and their 3D coordinates.
@rotated_matrix = rotate_l(\@matrix, 0);

sub rotate_l {
  my $ref = $_[0];
  my $x = 0;
  my $step = 1;

  #if rotx
  if ($_[1] == 0) {
    while ($$ref[$x][0]) {
      $$ref[$x][1] += ($$ref[$x][1]*cos($step) - $$ref[$x][2]*sin($step));
      $$ref[$x][2] += ($$ref[$x][1]*sin($step) + $$ref[$x][2]*cos($step));
      $x++;
    }
  }

  #if roty
  if ($_[1] == 1) {
    while ($$ref[$x][0]) {
      $$ref[$x][0] += ( $$ref[$x][0]*cos($step) + $$ref[$x][2]*sin($step));
      $$ref[$x][2] += (-$$ref[$x][0]*sin($step) + $$ref[$x][2]*cos($step));
      $x++;
    }
  }


  #if rotz
  if ($_[1] == 2) {
    while ($$ref[$x][0]) {
      $$ref[$x][0] += ($$ref[$x][0]*cos($step) - $$ref[$x][1]*sin($step));
      $$ref[$x][1] += ($$ref[$x][0]*sin($step) + $$ref[$x][1]*cos($step));
      $x++;
    }
  }

 return @$ref;
}
```

But something is wrong. Object size/form fails to stay same. And my math is not that good to realize why. I even not sure I need `+=` or `=`?

Comment: Does the C++ example work?

Comment: I strongly suspect that `$step` is to be multiplied by `2 pi`, and that all `+=` are to be replaced by `=`. Then it almost works.

Comment: I swear it took me more than a minute to realize that there was Perl code on this page.  I was about to ask in a comment: "what does this question have to do with Perl?  Do you want to translate this C++ to Perl?  What have you tried?"

Comment: Anyway, the likely culprit is that your while loops are structured to terminate upon reaching a sentinel -- like a C string function that's looking for the NUL byte.  This is meaningless in Perl.  You should loop over the elements of the arrays and modify them in place.

Comment: I do not know if C++ example work. This question has nothing other to do with Perl except that I use Perl interpreter to run it without errors or warnings. That looping is Ok, I check what amon suggested soon.

Answer (score 1):

Thx amon. As suggested this works:

```
#@matrix is points and their 3D coordinates.
@rotated_matrix = rotate_l(\@matrix, 0);

sub rotate_l {
  my $ref = $_[0];
  my $x = 0;
  my $step = pi;

  #if rotx
  if ($_[1] == 0) {
    while ($$ref[$x][0]) {
      $$ref[$x][1] = ($$ref[$x][1]*cos($step) - $$ref[$x][2]*sin($step));
      $$ref[$x][2] = ($$ref[$x][1]*sin($step) + $$ref[$x][2]*cos($step));
      $x++;
    }
  }

  #if roty
  if ($_[1] == 1) {
    while ($$ref[$x][0]) {
      $$ref[$x][0] = ( $$ref[$x][0]*cos($step) + $$ref[$x][2]*sin($step));
      $$ref[$x][2] = (-$$ref[$x][0]*sin($step) + $$ref[$x][2]*cos($step));
      $x++;
    }
  }


  #if rotz
  if ($_[1] == 2) {
    while ($$ref[$x][0]) {
      $$ref[$x][0] = ($$ref[$x][0]*cos($step) - $$ref[$x][1]*sin($step));
      $$ref[$x][1] = ($$ref[$x][0]*sin($step) + $$ref[$x][1]*cos($step));
      $x++;
    }
  }

 return @$ref;
}
```

If I need to rotate not around (0,0,0), but against other point the best way is to translate to 0 point rotate and then translate back?

Answer (score -1):

Just as an example of what I meant by what I recommend you do:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use common::sense;
use YAML 'Dump';

sub translate {
  my ($deltaX, $deltaY) = @{pop()};  # <-- don't mind this.
  for (@_) {    # <--- this is the important part
    $_->[0] += $deltaX;
    $_->[1] += $deltaY;
  }
  @_
}

my @points = ([0, 1], [0, -1], [-1, 0], [1, 0]);

print Dump([translate @points, [2, 2]]);

my $box = \@points;

print Dump([translate @$box, [5, 0]]);
```